# Next.js 13 - Is there a way to cache route handlers?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, caching, next.js, vercel

is there a way to cache Next.js 13 route handler so that it revalidates every 6 hours and uses the cached data for every visitor?

I have a firebase firestore db and there are 50 000 reads/day in the free plan.

On my page, I query a table where I need to return +- 2000 docs (2000 reads).

The data in the table is updated by corn job every 6 hours so it doesn't make sense to query the database and get the 2000 reads every time someone visits the page.

I use fetch("/api/...", { next: { revalidate: 21600 } }) (60s * 60m * 6h = 21600) which should cache it, but it seems like it caches it for every visitor on its own, meaning:

1. Visitor1 loads the page -> data is fetched and cached for 6 hours -> makes another request -> data is used from the cache
2. Visitor2 loads the page -> data is not used from the cache that was created for Visitor1, but it is fetched and cached for 6 hours for this user

So every time a new visitor comes, the first request is made to the db and costs 2000 reads, only after that the data is cached for that user.